# Reloading php-fpm after deploy via php-deployer without password

Tags: php, fpm, sudoers, php-deployer

What I'm trying to achieve is, to reload `php7.2-fpm` service via [php-deployer](https://deployer.org/).
 According to [php-deployer's documentation](https://deployer.org/docs/getting-started), it can be done like the code below:

```
task('reload:php-fpm', function () {
    run('sudo /usr/sbin/service php7-fpm reload');
});

after('deploy', 'reload:php-fpm');
```

However, I face the error below while deploying:

> ➤ Executing task deploy:reload_php_fpm
>
> ↳ on [prod]
>
> > sudo service php7.2-fpm reload
>
> In PhpSecLib.php line 124:
> [RuntimeException]
> **sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified**

System info:

> PHP Version 7.2 
> Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 
> PHP-Deployer Version 6.3.0

Do you have any idea how can I solve this issue?

Comment: does this help? https://appuals.com/fixed-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After digging around, I finally found the proper answer to handle the situation.
I edited `/etc/sudoers` file by following command:

```
sudo visudo
```

At the end of the file, I added this line:

```
siamak ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/etc/init.d/php7.2-fpm reload
```

It means that, the user `siamak` has permission to just reload `php7.2-fpm` without entering password. For any other administrative tasks, `siamak` must enter password.